# Browser zoom and .svg pictures

Tags: css, svg, zooming

I'm using .svg pictures which I made in Adobe Illustrator and I'm attaching them to a background with this css:

(the container)

```
.numbertable {
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 80%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:41%;
    }
```

(the picture)

```
.my-svg{ /* svg into : object, img or inline */
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%; /* only required for <img /> */
}
```

I then use the object command in html:

```
<object class="my-svg" type="image/svg+xml" data="/img/composite/scale2.svg" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
```

After much effort, I finally managed to make them look good in I.E. and Chrome using 100% (default) zoom, but when I switched to Firefox they apparently use different default zoom and the pictures are too big.

You can see it on the website: http://s23345.sigmabokhald.is/

What can I do to make the .svg pictures scale appropriately with zoom? So that if I zoom out and in (in my browser) then the picture scales appropriately with the background.

Comment: How does this fare when you use `<img src="path/to/svg" />` instead of an object? Images have more universal support and appear more predictable.

Comment: When I use the <img src> command instead of <object> then the image behaves very oddly in internet explorer. When I first open the page it looks fine, but when I click on a link to open the page the picture changes shape. It's hard to explain, I just haven't been able to make it work in IE but it worked fine in chrome and firefox with <img src>

Comment: You probably want to move one of those gears out a bit, so they don't all lock together. Try rotating one of them and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

I have shortly examined the behavior of your gears in the Mozilla and Chrome browser. (Lovely design, by the way :-) )

In my opinion, the gears stick to the size of your `<object>` box. This means, if you allow this box to "resize" if the browser zooms in and out, the gears adopt. By setting your `<object>` to 0,0/100%,100%, the gears cannot adopt.

You have this `.limit.tight` definition, which is a good sample for how the gear box should behave. So if I alter .my-svg like accordingly this:

```
.my-svg {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 960px;
}
```

I didn't change anything else. It works also with Chrome. Here is how the gears appear if I zoom with Mozilla:

[image: 150% Zoom]

[image: 30% Zoom]

[image: Settings]

I hope this is at last a good start, even if there could be more work for more browsers.

Comment: Thanks, that helped fix a lot of the zoom issues. The problem still persists on firefox with 100% zoom, the svg pic is slightly too large. I noticed why though and it's very odd, my Firefox browser appears to force the @media only screen and (max-width:1400px) , screen and (max-height:800px) settings even though I'm running windows in 1920x1080. My Chrome and IE browsers don't do that. And if I test the webpage on http://quirktools.com/screenfly using Firefox, it doesn't have this issue.